# How to set up Sublime 2 to forget the files opened on the application close?

Tags: sublimetext, mru

I'd like Sublime 2 to start with an empty window each time I start it (or with the single file opened if I start it by clicking on a file to edit). How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Sublime Text 2 from opening that last open file / project when starting up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890102/how-to-prevent-sublime-text-2-from-opening-that-last-open-file-project-when-st)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to do this.

Go to Preferences -> Global Settings – Default

And change the `"remember_open_files"` to `false` (instead of its default of `true`)
and change `"hot_exit"` to `false`.