# Sublime Text start without opening previous/old files

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime text opens, wants to reload old files because they have changed, I reload a few and then it crashes.

Is there a way to start Sublime Text afresh, letting it forget the last files that it had open?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890102/how-to-prevent-sublime-text-2-from-opening-that-last-open-file-project-when-st ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Sublime Text 2 from opening that last open file / project when starting up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890102/how-to-prevent-sublime-text-2-from-opening-that-last-open-file-project-when-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Sublime Text 3* set ***hot_exit*** to ***false*** in "Preferences -> Settings-User"

```
"hot_exit": false
```

*remember_open_files* doesn't exist in *Sublime Text 3* settings anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Sublime Text

Choose

> Preferences >> Settings-User

Add the code below to the current settings. (Remember to add a comma at the end of the first line if it doesn’t) and save it.

```
{
    "remember_open_files": false,
    "hot_exit": false,
}
```